# Draw Border on HorizontalScrollView Programmatically

Tags: android, background, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to draw a border on a HorizontalScrollView programmatically, and fill the inside with a diferent colour. I've tried different aproaches, with no success. I can only draw one thing at a time... Here's the last code i've tried.

```
private void applyViewBorder(View layout, String borderColor,
        String fillColor, int borderWidth) {
    if (fillColor == null || borderColor == null)
        return;
    RectShape rect = new RectShape();
    ShapeDrawable rectShapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(rect);
    Paint paint = rectShapeDrawable.getPaint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(borderColor));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(rectShapeDrawable);
    } else {
        layout.setBackground(rectShapeDrawable);
    }
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(fillColor));
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(rectShapeDrawable);
    } else {
        layout.setBackground(rectShapeDrawable);
    }

}
```

I've already searched in stack overflow, with no success too...
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

what you can try is

Create XML called border.xml in project  drawable folder as below :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item> 
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#FF0000" /> 
    </shape>
  </item>   
    <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp"  android:top="5dp" >  
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"> 
      <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
   </item>    
 </layer-list>
```

and than

```
yourshorizontalscrollview.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
```

or use this one :

```
yourshorizontalscrollview.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.border));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. But this time, I cannot do this way. It's an obligation do it programmatically..